# black screen on boot. screen reappears after closing and opening lid

Tags: 14.04

i'm using ubuntu 14.04 and i'm facing a problem whereby everytime when i boot up, after the the ubuntu logo, my screen just stays black. I have to close and open the lid of my laptop in order to see the screen again. What's the cause of this problem? How can i fix it? I'm using an Nvidia GT820M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

it seems, that there is again a regression for the Nvidia driver and the gpu-manager of Ubuntu.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1362848

This is an everlasting and frequently returning problem. Normally this gets fixed within a short time. In the meanwhile you could try a newer driver from ubuntu's ["fresh graphics driver"](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) ppa or switch to an intel GPU (if your notebook offers this option) by switching to tty1 (Ctrl+alt+F1), login and `sudo prime-select intel` followed by `sudo service lightdm restart` (the same procedure with "nvidia" instead of intel for switching back).
Hope this helps fixing your Problem temporarily.

Comment: hmmm but if i want to play games like dota 2, will it switch back and use the nvidia driver?

Comment: It will not switch back automatically. The switch is done by choosing the gpu via prime-select an "rebooting the notebook" or "restart your lightdm-session". If you use the default unity-desktop, you could add the "prime-indicator" which is explained by this link:
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

Comment: yeah i did exactly what you said... apparently, everytime after i switch to nvidia, my whole OS just crashes after logging off. Then it'll show me some screen that says about restarting display and a bunch of codes. I have to manually power it off by holding the power button and powering it on again.

Comment: All I can say is that you will have to keep track of the launchpad bug I mentioned above and wait for a fix. The bug lists all nvidia versions from 331 to 364 as "affected". If you can't wait for a fix you could try upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But there is no guarantee if it will help.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and facing the same issue (only when external monitor is connected lid stays blank though)